# Building xml file for amazon product feed

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, formatting

So I'm trying to build a feed to submit to amazon, and it tells me I need a country of origin field.

From what I researched I have it in the right place, but I still get an error.
I have tried placing it in multiple locations in the xml file and nothing works.

Here is the error:

```
XML Parsing Error at Line 39, Column 22: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'CountryOfOrigin'
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
  <Header>
    <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
    <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANT_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
  </Header>
  <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
  <PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
  <Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
  <SKU>5678999993</SKU>
  <StandardProductID>
    <Type>ASIN</Type>
    <Value>5678999993</Value>
  </StandardProductID>
  <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
  <DescriptionData>
    <Title>MULE 3L - Racing Red/Pitch Blue</Title>
    <Brand>CAMELBAK</Brand>
    <Description>This is a test product description.</Description>
    <BulletPoint>Perfect for hiking.</BulletPoint>
    <BulletPoint>Bladder for hydration.</BulletPoint>
    <MSRP currency="AUD">100.00</MSRP>
    <Manufacturer>CAMELBAK</Manufacturer>
    <ItemType>outdoor-backpacks</ItemType>
  </DescriptionData>
  <ProductData>
    <Outdoors>
      <ProductType>
        <OutdoorRecreationProduct>

        </OutdoorRecreationProduct>
      </ProductType>
      <VariationData>
      </VariationData>
      <CountryOfOrigin>US</CountryOfOrigin>
    </Outdoors>
  </ProductData>
</Product>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Comment: I had similar issue,where everything looked alright.The problem was ,some special character was copy - pasted,and was not visible in editor.I got that resolved by typing in couple of lines manually.Can you please check and let us know meanwhile we look for other possibility?Thanks.

Comment: Is that the whole XML file? Certainly a file that starts with AmazonEnvelope and ends with /Product is not valid

Comment: @Mahesh_Loya I will give that a go thanks :)

Comment: @KevinBrown sorry about that, the last 2 elements were in my question, just not showing in the code snippet which is a bit odd

Comment: Ok so for an update to this problem, I'm using the AU scratchpad. I have been in touch with amazon devs and they have confirmed there are bugs with the AU scratchpad. So I am working with them to resolve any bugs I find.
Thanks for having a look Mahesh & Kevin :)

Answer (score 4):

I've just encountered similar problems to you, not helped by the Amazon web site naming the field a selection of ways;
You are correct with 'CountryOfOrigin', as you have no doubt found by now.
After much searching through XSD files on the web site, and experimenting by submitting files, I found putting it as the last entry in the < DescriptionData > section of the XML worked;
In XML format, it also needs the two letter Country code (eg CN for China), as not mentioned anywhere on the Amazon website.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).